# How to know object is stopped.object is forced by rigid body

Tags: unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I am Making Game Using Unity3d with Monodevelop(c#).
I m trying to detect event when my marble(Sphere) is stopped.
My marble is moving using Rigidbody.Addforce() method.
Is there any way i can found the way??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rigidbody.velocity.magnitude` will give you the speed with which your object is traveling. It is the magnitude of the velocity vector. Using that, you can check when your object's speed has reached zero:

```
if(rigidbody.velocity.magnitude == 0.0f) {
    Debug.Log("object has stopped.");
}
```

However, in my experience, the object's speed will take forever to reach zero. It'll keep moving very very very very very slowly. Rather, its velocity vector's magnitude will never quite hit zero unless you've got strong friction.

To compensate for this, figure out a good speed at which the object has "basically stopped". For instance, if the speed is below 0.0001, it has probably "stopped" in the sense that it isn't going to move much more. You'll have to experiment to determine what that value should be:

```
float stopThreshold=0.001f;

if(rigidbody.velocity.magnitude <= stopThreshold) {
    Debug.Log("object has mostly stopped.");
}
```

But the concept remains the same: use `rigidbody.velocity.magnitude` to determine the speed of your object.

Comment: I want to destroy my object when it is stopped.But When i use rigidbody.velocity.magnitude,magnitude value starts increasing from 0.so my object destroyed just at start of force :( [Rnu](http://variyasoftsolutions.com/unity3d.html)

Comment: Well you just have to make sure you only start checking once the object is in already in motion.

Comment: I solved it!I started checking for magnitude after it increased from zero.  [Rnu](http://variyasoftsolutions.com/unity3d.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can check the object rigidbody velocity or angular velocity if less than your threshold w/c i think is better < 0.1f;

```
if(rigidbody.velocity.sqrMagnitude < .01  || rigidbody.angularVelocity.sqrMagnitude < .01) { Debug.Log ( "OBJECT STOPPED ");  }
```